# Why JSON empty string deserializes to null at the server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm sending empty string through $.post and it deserializes to null. How to differentiate if the string was empty or null at the client side ?

Regards

**UPDATE**
What I'm actually doing is:

```
$.post("Controller/Action", $.param({Name: ""}, true), null, "json");
```

at the server:

```
public Container
{
   public string Name;
}

public void Action(Container container)
{
    bool c = container.Name == null;   // c is true, why ?     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable with empty value is written in JSON as:

```
{ "var" : "" }
```

An empty string is parsed as null as there is no object defined in it.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "empty string" ?

The JSON representation of an empty string is `""`, not an empty string. An empty string actually means "*nothing*", so **null**